# Manga where the main character is reincarnated and wakes up in a fully automated castle

Tags: story-identification, manga

I’m trying to remember the name of the manga where the main character gets reincarnated or something similar to that. They wake up in a giant floating castle that is self automated where the mc doesn’t have to do anything but they are the only person inside the castle. The guards are automated robots. I remember part of a chapter where the mc is watching what is happening on the ground and sees a girl getting chased by bandits and decides to have her saved and sends one of the robots to go and save her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for *Tenkuu no Shiro o Moratta no de Isekai de Tanoshiku Asobitai*, aka *[I Want To Play Happily Because I Got The Heavenly Castle](https://mangakakalot.com/read-mm9qn158504899851)*.

[image: Front cover of *I Want to Play Happily Because I Got The Heavenly Castle*]

> An angel made a mistake, resulting in Shiihara Daiki’s death. In order to hide the mistake, he was then sent to a different world. The angel will grant him one wish as a payment for keeping it a secret. Daiki asked for a Heavenly Castle floating in the sky without hesitation.
> Suddenly a floating castle appeared in the new world, which causes confusion amongst the people. They attempt to contact Daiki in various ways. A country tries to steal it by force, while another seeks to befriend him. What in the world will Daiki do?

Indeed, within the first chapter, he rescues a girl from bandits by the robots.

Found with a search for `manga isekai robot castle`

Comment: Thank you it was driving me nuts trying to remember and searching it on google how i said it didnt help they just gave me other isekai results

Comment: Sometimes it's just a matter of finding the right combination of keywords.

Comment: And truthfully, since Google customizes search results, sometimes a query really will work for one person and not another...